# Jeffreys prior vs. Flat prior on $(\beta,\log\sigma^2)$

Tags: bayesian, uninformative-prior, jeffreys-prior

I'm reading *Bayesian Core*, and the authors state that a Jeffreys prior $\pi(\beta,\sigma^2|X)\propto\frac{1}{\sigma^2}$ corresponds to a flat prior on $(\beta,\log\sigma^2)$. Why is this so?

Comment: Note that $$\mathrm{d}\log \sigma^2 = \frac{1}{\sigma^2}\,\mathrm{d}\sigma^2.$$

Comment: @whuber: what else to add?!